# Why this behaviour (on ALL browsers) with margin-top?

Tags: html, css

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfg8D/1/) is my code :

## HTML

```
<div class='father'>
    <div class='son'>Son</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.father
{
    background-color:blue;  
}

.son
{
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
}
```

Where is the `background-color` blue of the father?
I know how to fix this problem (putting `padding-top:1px` to the father) but I'd like to know why of this behaviour!

For me it doesnt make sense, because on every browsers, not only IE, this is the behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of Collapsing Margins. You can read a [good article by Eric Meyer](http://www.complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/) on this topic where he illustrates this exact behavior. The following image is from his article.

[image]

Here's what the CSS2 specification has to say about it.

#### 8.3.1 Collapsing margins

> If the top and bottom margins of a box are adjoining, then it is
> possible for margins to collapse through it. In this case, the
> position of the element depends on its relationship with the other
> elements whose margins are being collapsed.
>
> - If the element's margins are collapsed with its parent's top margin,    the top border edge of the box is defined to be the same as
>   the    parent's.
> - Otherwise, either the element's parent is not taking part    in the margin collapsing, or only the parent's bottom margin is    involved.
>   The position of the element's top border edge is the same    as it
>   would have been if the element had a non-zero bottom border.
>
> Note that the positions of elements that have been collapsed through
> have no effect on the positions of the other elements with whose
> margins they are being collapsed; the top border edge position is only
> required for laying out descendants of these elements.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: One way to show this is to add padding of just one px to the 'Father' div.

Comment: But this is not true! In fact if I add padding-top:1px to the <li> (to prevent margin-collapse) the result works anyway http://jsfiddle.net/Tfg8D/16/ (i see the "disc" correctly)

Comment: @markzzz I don't understand what you are trying to say in your previous comment.

Comment: I mean : if un-collapsing margin show the List incorrectly (Figure 5 on your tutorial), putting padding-top:1px on the <li> (so I don't collapse margin) I should see that list wrong (so, I should see it as Figure 5). But in fact I see it correctly...

Comment: Here's an example with the `padding-top: 1px` fix. http://jsfiddle.net/Tfg8D/21/ - And here's another example without the  `padding-top: 1px` fix. http://jsfiddle.net/Tfg8D/22/ - They are different. I don't see why you think this doesn't line up with what Eric Meyer wrote in his article.

Comment: Yeah, but, I mean : putting padding-top:1px, I should uncollapse the margin. So the list should be "wrong", as Figure 5. But in fact it is correct anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the div is a block-level element. Certain block-level elements don't contain any padding by default. Divs are one such element. Block-level elements will take up the entire height and width of the container while respecting any padding it may contain.

[W3C Visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)

The parent element's height is set to its content's height by default. Once you set a height on the parent, that's no longer the default. Checking up on it, I believe that the padding adds to the height. So, the height is originally determined by the content unless otherwise stated in the CSS. Then, in most cases (IE 6 may be the exception), the padding is added to the height.

Good thing about SO, it helps us be much more detailed in our responses. :)

Comment: Not true. In this example `.son` does not take up the entire height of the container.  http://jsfiddle.net/Tfg8D/3/

Comment: The parent element's height is set to its content's height by default. Once you set a height on the parent, that's no longer the default. It's been changed, that's why it doesn't apply in your example. ;)

Comment: If you add that clause into your answer, I will remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, block level elements naturally fills the elements content area, so your "son" div is filling your "father" div completely. Of course, you can bypass this by adding margin/padding/height to your parent div.

Comment: But it doesnt make sense! Putting a padding-top:1px should filling only 1 pixel of background than, not the whole father :O

Comment: You have to remember that the parent block element is still a block level element. Padding is used to "clear" an area around the content, if the parent block doesn't have any defining properties (such as padding/margin/height) it will just inherit all of this qualities from the child block and "push" along with it.

Comment: Which brings us to the "padding-top" bit, since you're adding padding to the top of the parent block, you are defining a block-level quality to it and so it will flow naturally as instructed instead of inheriting these values from the child element. And so, padding-top+margin-top = height of the parent block, in this case, which is 51px.

Answer (score -2):

You're setting blue explicitly:

```
.father {
    background-color:blue;  
}
```

It's overridden (thanks to the "C" in CSS a.k.a cascading) but the style remains on your parent element (here, appropriately named "father").

If your `.father` box receives any height at all (check in the Firebug/Chrome dev tools inspector) than the blue is going to show through. I am guessing this is what you're seeing in IE (that or perhaps there's a flash of content before your child element style comes in). I don't think the IE debug tools show bounding boxes but you can test the element for it's height using JavaScript.

Comment: If you look at the JSfiddle, the issue is that the father div is *not* blue, not that it is.

Comment: This has nothing to do with cascading styles.

Comment: What's mean with my question?

Comment: I wish I could downvote this answer twice because someone upvoted it after I downvoted.

Comment: I may have missed the point of this question but collapsing margins has everything to do with CSS.

Answer (score -2):

Moving outwards from the content, you have padding, border, and margin (as you probably know). Background covers only padding, but not margin.

Comment: Yeah, but margin is "transparent", and the father's background is blue!